# Could Not Connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql, connection

I am new to Ubuntu and using **Ubuntu Server 14.40 LTS**. I am trying to connect my MySQL database to show database data on a PHP file, but I am not able to connect it. Furthermore, I am getting error `Could Not Connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` when I open that PHP file and when I open my PhpMyAdmin then I got `#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server` and  `Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.`

Just after installing Ubuntu, I opened my PHP page outside from server and then was not able to connect the database or even not getting any error. Then searching over Google, I changed `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `# bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to allow connection in
`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but after this I got the above two error.

My connection file is below...

```php
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "my_username";
$password = "my_password";
$dbname = "my_database";
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Could Not Connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
?>
```

In addition, my `port 80` is blocked my ISP and I am using `port 7550` for Apache. I also have a dynamic IP. Please consider these limitation and tell me How to connect to mysql server? Please answer using terminal.

Comment: You checked that your MySQL server was really running, don't you ? (`status mysql`).

Comment: @Benoit My `mysql` is online and working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying myself too after posting the question here and I got it working through following the below steps. This work in mycase. You can try it too.

1. Open Terminal In Ubuntu.
2. Type `mysql -u root -p`
3. *ENTER_YOUR_SQL_PASSWORD*
4. Type `> grant all privileges on DATABASE_NAME.* to
   USERNAME@IPADDRESS identified by 'PASSWORD';`
5. Or
6. Type `> grant all privileges on DATABASE_NAME.* to
   USERNAME@localhost identified by 'PASSWORD';`
7. Change `USERNAME`, `IPADDRESS`, `PASSWORD` With Your Data.
8. Type `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
9. Now Restart SQL Typing `sudo service mysql start`
10. Close Terminal.

After this you can connect your database from outside to server too. If you have better contribution then share that also.

Note: Keep in kind that you have to changed `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `# bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to allow connection in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` also.